# How to get a constant string value for a new field in Google data studio?

Tags: formula, looker-studio

I am using Google Data Studio and I have a report that draws data from a source with x fields.

When editing the data source I create a new field with the following formula:

```
CASE
    WHEN (field_1 IS NOT NULL OR field_1 IS NULL) THEN "foo"
    ELSE "bar"
END
```

that should return "foo" for every row of that data source since the statement is always true.

Initially I tried something like `foo` or `"foo"`or

```
CASE
    WHEN (True) THEN "foo"
END
```

for the formula but I got the error for invalid formula.

My issue is that it returns "bar" for every row.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `CONCAT('foo','')` as the formula?